# Oracle pipelined function with cache

Tags: oracle, plsql, pipelined-function

How can use oracle pipelined function on query to fetch data only first time.

example:

```
create or replace function best_employees return my_type pipelined;

select * from employees a 
join table(best_employees) b 
on a.employee_id = b.employee_id;
```

this query is calling best_employees function more than one time. It must call only first time.
How can i do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While you could store the results in a package collection of type `my_type` and write the function to return that if it contained values instead of re-executing the query, the simpler and more reliable approach would be to use the [`result_cache`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF20004) hint in its query.

```
select /*+ result_cache */ kitten_id, cuteness from kittens where colour = 'BLACK';
```

(There is also a [`result_cache` option for functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00817) but it cannot be used for pipelined functions.)

Comment: So is it "not working" or "working", and what do those terms mean? The function will of course be executed every time it is called. The `result_cache` hint is to cache the results from the SQL inside it.

Comment: best_employees  function working everytime. I want that it works only first time. Then it must take from cache